# calipso.js and nodejitsu

Tags: node.js, nodejitsu

I've trying to setup my calipso site with nodejitsu mongo database.

On **Step 1: Configure MongoDB** I copied *Connection url* from jitsu databases list and put it into *MongoDB URI* field. All works fine as on **Create Admin User** step.
But on the third (**Add Features**) step, after I clicked on the *Save Configuration and Install* button (with default settings) I have:

> Whups. We'll try to lock that down.
>
> Something on the server didn't work quite right.
>
> (500)

on the page.

and

> undefined

in the console.

After all, when I trying do it with local mongo database - everything worked allright.

Any suggestion what I doing wrong and how I can use calipso site on the nodejitsu hosting?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you just have your mongodb misconfigured. What logs do you see when you run `jitsu logs app`? Perhaps they include more details about the error you're seeing.

Comment: Actually, I didn't deploy my app, when trying to "install" it, as I wrote above. I launched it locally with remote  mongo database.
But when I do, It still just "undefined" in app logs.